# Convert OpenCV Mat to UIImage

Tags: swift, objective-c, opencv, bridging-header

My goal is to process image from camera frame using openCV and then display the processed image back to user on UI.

I added opencv2.framework into my project (4.7.0), created OpenCVWrapper.h and OpenCVWrapper.mm.

Opencv2 provides me possibility to create Mat object from image, by init:
`let mat = Mat(uiImage: someImage)` 
So i converted image from camera to Mat object, then performed some operations, and the last step I want to do is to convert it back to UIImage so I can display it to user.

As far as I know, there is no similar opposite init (Mat -> UIImage), so I created functions in my wrapper.
In OpenWrapper.mm (from docs of openCV, [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/def/tutorial_image_manipulation.html))[(https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/def/tutorial_image_manipulation.html) ) :

```
\+(UIImage \*)UIImageFromCVMat:(cv::Mat)cvMat
{
NSData \*data = \[NSData dataWithBytes:cvMat.data length:cvMat.elemSize()\*cvMat.total()\];
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;
if (cvMat.elemSize() == 1) {
colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
} else {
colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
}
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((\__bridge CFDataRef)data);
// Creating CGImage from cv::Mat
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(cvMat.cols, //width
cvMat.rows, //height
8, //bits per component
8 \* cvMat.elemSize(), //bits per pixel
cvMat.step\[0\], //bytesPerRow
colorSpace, //colorspace
kCGImageAlphaNone|kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault,// bitmap info
provider, //CGDataProviderRef
NULL, //decode
false, //should interpolate
kCGRenderingIntentDefault //intent
);
// Getting UIImage from CGImage
UIImage \*finalImage = \[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef\];
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
return finalImage;
}
```

and in OpenCVWrapper.h :

`+ (UIImage \*)UIImageFromCVMat:(Mat \*)cvMat;` 
but when I call this function simply like this:

```
let image = UIImage()
let matImage = Mat(uiImage: image)
let backUIImage = OpenCVWrapper.uiImage(fromCVMat: matImage)
```

I am getting error:
`Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x113f41cb0)` 
Anyone has idea what am I doing wrong ?
Thanks for any tips